# Kotlin Stateflow new value emitted but not collected

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel, kotlin-stateflow

I have a fragment that shows a location after collecting it from the viewmodel stateflow, the location is stored in shared preferences than emitted to a mutableflowstate when the fragment starts.

The fragment can show a BottomSheetDialogue, in the BottomSheetDialog the user can update the location, I am updating the location via the viewmodel in both shared prefs and the mutablestateflow.

The problem is when the new location is updated, and the bottom sheet is dismissed the new value is not collected in the fragment, or the collector is not notified.

I am not sure exactly what I am doing wrong here.

**Fragment**

```
val viewModel: LocationViewModel by viewModels() lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewLifecycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                viewModel.shippingLocation.collect { location ->
                    if (location != null) {
                        binding.shippingLocation.text = location
                    } else {
                        binding.shippingLocation.text = ""
                    }
                }
            }
        }

binding.shippingLocationEditBtn.setOnClickListener {
                val editLocationSheet = EditLocationFragment()
                editLocationSheet.show(parentFragmentManager, "EditLocationSheet")
            }
```

**ViewModel**

```
    private val _shippingLocation = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
    val shippingLocation: StateFlow<String?> = _shippingLocation.asStateFlow()


    init {
        getShippingLocation()
    }

    fun updateShippingLocation(location: String?) {
        sharedPreferences.edit()
            .putString(PREFS_SHIPPING_LOCATION_KEY, location)
            .apply()
        _shippingLocationWilaya.value = location
    }

    private fun getShippingLocation() {
        val location = sharedPreferences.getString(PREFS_SHIPPING_LOCATION_KEY, null)
        viewModelScope.launch {
            if (location == null) {
                _shippingLocation.value = ""
            } else {
                _shippingLocation.value = location
            }
        }
    }
```

**BottomSheetDialog**

```
val viewModel: LicationViewModel by viewModels()
binding.editShippingLocationTopAppBar.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
            when (menuItem.itemId) {
                R.id.saveShippingLocation -> {
                    if (location != null) {
                        viewModel.updateShippingLocation(location)
                        dismiss()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireContext(),
                            "Please select a location",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are collecting the value only on the view started state which means the value will be collected only when the view started not every time it changes its value.

You need to collect the value every time it changes.

```
val viewModel: LocationViewModel by viewModels()

lifecycleScope.launch {
    viewModel.shippingLocation.collect { location ->
        binding.shippingLocation.text = location.orEmpty()
    }
}

binding.shippingLocationEditBtn.setOnClickListener {
    val editLocationSheet = EditLocationFragment()
    editLocationSheet.show(parentFragmentManager, "EditLocationSheet")
}
```

Comment: This does not work, the coroutinescope also does not work, i have monitored the lifecycle of the fragment and i have noticed that it does not change when the bottomsheetdialog is shown, it stays in the onResume state even after showing and hiding the dialog fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the problem is that I am not having the same instance of the viewmodel, in each fragment a new instance of the viewmodel (with a new data) is created.

I thought that the `viewModels()` function is used with `hilt` ( *`@HiltViewModel` notation at the viewmodel level*) to create a `shared viewmodel` across fragments, but it turned out that i was wrong about this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem;

> `init { getShippingLocation() }`

this part is not working.

Maybe, you can add Dispatcher to your **getShippingLocation** function,
you can try by doing public function and remove init block, if it is okay for you.